# Does jqueryui have CSS rules for normal HTML elements?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-frameworks, jquery-ui-css-framework

As I have understood, jqueryui has 2 sets of things:

- Ready made elements that can be used in developing web apps (like menu, datepicker and so so...)
- CSSs ready to use with the elements talked about before

---

Now my question is:

Are the CSSs ready to be used for **Normal HTML Elements**, too? Like `form`s, `ul` and `ol` lists, `a`s, and others?

This way, standard HTML elements' style can be compatible with other jqueryui widgets.

Are there also some ready `.half`, `.third`, `.full-width` classes for `div`s?

Unfortunately I couldn't get the answer even after reading http://api.jqueryui.com/category/theming, http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/ and http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/stacking-elements/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, jQuery UI doesn't include anything that you mentioned.

jQuery UI is based on widgets. You call one of those widgets on top of your elements and *"let the magic happen"*.

The only styles that you *may* use in your application CSS are:

- `.ui-helper-hidden`: to hide your element;
- `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible`: to hide your element, but let it be "accessible"
- `.ui-helper-reset`
- `.ui-helper-clearfix`: [The famous clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)
- `.ui-helper-zfix`
- All the `.ui-icon`s

**About the other styles you mentioned:**
For styling other elements like forms, lists and the grid system (the `.half`, `.full` & etc part of your question), I'd recommend you to give a try to [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), if you already haven't.

Comment: Thank you very much `:)` I thought that Bootstrap and jQueryUI where alternatives. OK, what other alternatives are there to Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html) and discover what best fits to you :)

Comment: Perfect comparison list. Thank you much more!